# trimming strings in python 3

Tags: python, whitespace, trim

I have this function to get a file type :

```
def get_file_type():
try:
    cmd = ['/usr/bin/file', '/home/user']
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    p = str(p).split(':')[1:]
    if len(p) > 1:
        ' : '.join(p).strip().replace('\\n', '')
    else:
        p = p[0].strip().replace('\\n', '')
    print(p)
except CalledProcessError:
    print('unknown')
```

But it returns this : directory'
The ending apostrophe is not a typo, it is what bothers me. And I don't understand why (not that it bothers me.. ;) )

Thank you

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. What is the value of `p` prior to the reassignment?

Comment: When `len(p) > 1`, you are performing a join, strip, and replace that you are *throwing away the result of*.  You presumably want to assign that back to `p`.

Comment: @tobias_k p before reassignment : [" directory\\n'"]

Comment: @jasonharper yes ^^ thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating bytes as a string and you're using Python3.  So what you're getting when you call `str(p)` looks like this:

```
"b'/home/user: directory\\n'"
```

You could fix this by doing `p.decode().split` instead of `str(p).split`

Comment: I'm currently upgrading to python3, I thought it was the right way to bytes to string : I know now it isn't. Thanks !